# How repair windows user profile after interrupted backup

Tags: windows-7, archiving, user-profiles, windows-7-backup

I interrupted windows 7 backup, so after reboot, windows load in temp profile, in list of user's profiles, it marks like a archiving profile. Deleting profile status in reestr don't work.
How to change the status of the user's profile?

Comment: Not sure why a backup tool would corrupt the original. Are you sure you don't have a disk or file system problem?

Answer (score 0):

There will be an event logged in the event log for sure, so click start, type eventvwr and wait for the summary to load and see errors summary from last hour or just go to custom views / administrative events and there should be something related to the profile loading.

If you don't find the solution or it will seem too complex, consider creating new user account and after logging into it copy the files from desktop, documents, favorites, appdata/mozilla and such from the corrupted one...